# Swift - Issue accessing data from UICollectionView embedded in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uistoryboardsegue

I have a tableView, with a prototype cell containing a UICollectionView. I’ve setup the tableView according to this tutorial (https://medium.com/@stasost/ios-how-to-build-a-table-view-with-multiple-cell-types-2df91a206429), and the UI is working. I can pass data through my tableView and into the collectionView.

[View Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2hGb.jpg)

When a collectionViewCell is selected it segues to another view.

I haven’t figured out how to access the data from the collectionViewCell and pass it to the new view.

The collectionView is initialized within the tableView prototype cell. I've tried didSelectRow -> prepareForSegue (code below), but the commands do not autocomplete, and are not working.

Here's the code for the tableViewCell, where the collectionView is setup.

---

EDIT: Removed commented code for clarity

```
import UIKit

class homeFeedTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var feedCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var selectedEvent : Event? 

    var collectionItems = [CollectionViewModelItem]()
    var collectionItem : CollectionViewModelItem?

    @IBOutlet weak var sectionHeadingLabel: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        feedCollectionView.delegate = self
        feedCollectionView.dataSource = self

        print("collection items \(collectionItems.count)")
        for item in collectionItems{print("type: \(item.type), title: \(item.eventTitle)")}

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    //    setup view model
      var item: TableViewModelItem? {
                didSet {
    //                if not right class, skip
                    guard let item = item as? TableViewModelFeed else {
                        return
                    }
                    sectionHeadingLabel.text = item.sectionTitle
                }
            }

    //    create reuse identifier property
            static var identifier: String {
                return String(describing: self)
            }



}


import Foundation
import UIKit

extension homeFeedTableViewCell {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
//    print("dataCount3: \(collectionItems.count) \(collectionItems[collectionItems.count-1].type)")
    return collectionItems.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
//    let cell = UICollectionViewCell()
//    return cell

    self.collectionItem = collectionItems[indexPath.row]

    switch collectionItem!.type {
    case .yourEvents:
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:YourEventsCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? YourEventsCollectionViewCell{

            cell.item = collectionItem
            print(cell.item?.type)
            print(".yourEvents")
            return cell
        }
    case .feed:
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: mainFeedCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? mainFeedCollectionViewCell{
            cell.item = collectionItem
            print(".feed")

            return cell
        }
    }
    return UICollectionViewCell()

}

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("\(collectionItems[indexPath.row].eventTitle) tapped")

        func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "yourEventsToEventViewController" || segue.identifier == "feedToEventViewController"{
                print("prepare for segue1")
                let destinationVC = segue.destination as! EventViewController
                if collectionItem != nil{
                    print("prepare for segue2")
                    destinationVC.backgroundImageUrl = collectionItem!.backgroundImageUrl
                }
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A UICollectionView keeps track of its selected indexPaths with the property [indexPathsForSelectedItems](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618099-indexpathsforselecteditems).  Since you trigger your segue in `collectionView(didSelectItem: atIndexPath:)`, your selected indexPath is available during `prepare(forSegue:)`.  You could try the following:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    ...

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)
    }

    ...

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

        guard let destinationVC = segue.destination as! EventViewController,
            segue.identifier == "mySegue" else { return }

        // In this context, your selected cell is the one who fired the segue

        if let selectedIndexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems,
            let firstSelectedIndexPath = selectedIndexPaths.first {

            let selectedObject = collectionItems[firstSelectedIndexPath.row]

            destinationVC?.backgroundUrl = selectedObject.backgroundUrl
        }
    }
}
```

The sequence is:

1. You select a cell (through user interaction, ie tapping).
2. `didSelect` performs a segue named "mySegue" (in this example).
3. In `prepareForSegue`, you look for your selected index paths.  Assuming you aren't using multi-selection, you want your first and only indexPath.  Using that index path, you can retrieve your data in your `collectionItems` array.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I was able to clean up the selected object using the indesPath as suggested, but the performSegue() and prepare(for segue) functions aren't available, since my UICollectionViewDelegate is of class UITableViewCell, instead of UIViewController. I can use the function from the main view controller, but I can't figure out how to access the information from my TableViewCell -> collectionViewCell from the viewController level. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Got it.  Haven't had a chance to revisit yet.  I'll come up with a better response a little later today.

Comment: One quick idea that comes to mind is having a delegate from your collectionViewCell back to your view controller.  `UIView`'s are just that - UI.  They aren't meant to control things like navigation directly, so they aren't able to perform segues or anything like that.  That responsibility belongs to `UIViewController`, so somehow, you have to handle the call there.